Remove value but keep color for insignificant correlations using ggcorrplot
I am using ggcorrplot to visualize a correlation matrix. How can I show the correlation coefficient value inside the plot only if it is significant? For non-significant correlations there should be no value displayed but the color should still be present.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)

# Make correlation coefficient matrix 
corr <- round(cor(mtcars),1)

# Make p-value matrix associated with the correlation coefficients
corr_p <- cor_pmat(mtcars)

# Shows all of the correlation coefficients
ggcorrplot(corr,
           lab = TRUE)



# Puts a X over the non-significant correlations
ggcorrplot(corr,
           lab = TRUE,
           p.mat = corr_p)



# Removes the value of non-significant correlations but also removes color
# I want to keep the color
ggcorrplot(corr,
           lab = TRUE,
           p.mat = corr_p,
           insig = 'blank')


Created on 2024-05-17 with reprex v2.1.0

Simplified version of NoNameBoyy's answer, by using a function in the data argument to geom_text:
corr <- cor(mtcars)
corr_p <- cor_pmat(mtcars)

p <- ggcorrplot(corr, lab = FALSE, p.mat = corr_p, sig.level = 1)

p + geom_text(
  aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, label = round(value, 1)),
  \(d) subset(d, pvalue < 0.05)
)


For those who come across this post,  see this follow-up question about only showing the upper or lower part of the matrix.

You can achieve it by using geom_text() (converting to a long format dataframe)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)

# Make correlation coefficient matrix 
corr <- round(cor(mtcars),1)

# Make p-value matrix associated with the correlation coefficients
corr_p <- cor_pmat(mtcars)

corr_df <- reshape2::melt(corr)
names(corr_df) <- c("Var1", "Var2", "value")

p_df <- reshape2::melt(corr_p)
names(p_df) <- c("Var1", "Var2", "pvalue")

corr_df <- merge(corr_df, p_df, by = c("Var1", "Var2"))

p <- ggcorrplot(corr, lab = FALSE)

p + geom_text(data = subset(corr_df, pvalue < 0.05), 
              aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, label = value))


